# Getting layout elements in activiy

Tags: android

I have an activity with buttons on them. When I click the button the text of the buttons change. I am adding a share menu to share the new values of the buttons with other apps. Whenever I try to access the text values of the buttons in onCreateOptionsMenu I get the original values and not the new values.

How can I access the new values?

Comment: `The onCreate method is called first, and before it finishes onCreateOptionsMenu is called.` Basically you're getting the original values because at the time onCreateOptionsMenu is called, the values haven't changed yet. Try calling `invalidateOptionsMenu();` after changing the values; this will cause onCreateOptionsMenu to be called again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreateOptionsMenu()` is called when the menu is first created. At that time, the text in the buttons is the original one. So you should call `invalidateOptionsMenu();` each time you click the button and the text is changed. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13180423/1039555).

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to share variables to another apps?
You can use putExtra in Intent or Share preferences.
Try this topic [How to send data from one application to other application in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355860/how-to-send-data-from-one-application-to-other-application-in-android)