# How transfer data from one app to another app in android

Tags: android, android-intent, onresume

I have two application , `com.appone.one`  and `com.apptwo.two`.

I want transfer data from `appone` to `apptwo` ,I want when a data transferred to `apptwo` , `apptwo` opens or if open only come up(onResume) and show that data.
I wrote this code:

com.appone.one:

```
 Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
                    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.apptwo.two");
                    i.putExtra("MessageText",""+Connect.MessageArrive.toString());
                   i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 
startActivity(i);
```

com.apptwo.two:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("MessageText");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),String.valueOf(name), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

I want only write this line :

```
String name=getIntent().getStringExtra("MessageText");
```

in `OnResume` because I don't want apptwpo load again,If I write this line in `onCreate` , my code works fine. but I want that in `onResume`.
Now `apptwo` returns null :(

what should I do?
thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data from one application to other application in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355860/how-to-send-data-from-one-application-to-other-application-in-android)

Comment: no , I test that post now, didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with this link:
http://androiddhamu.blogspot.in/2012/03/share-data-across-application-in.html

appone:

```
  SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("demopref",
                             Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                     SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                     editor.putString("demostring", ""+Connect.MessageArrive.toString());
                     editor.commit();

                  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DATE_CHANGED);
                    PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
                    i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.graphhopper.android");
                   // i.putExtra("MessageText",""+Connect.MessageArrive.toString());
                   i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER); 


                  //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    startActivity(i);
```

apptwo:

```
  @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
            con = createPackageContext("com.appone.one", 0);
            SharedPreferences pref = con.getSharedPreferences(
                    "demopref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            String data = pref.getString("demostring", "No Value");
}
```

Comment: MODE_WORLD_READABLE got depreciated in API 17 and was totally removed form android in API 24

better don't rely on it

Comment: MODE_WORLD_READABLE is deprecated. If you use this you got SecurityException

Answer (score 3):

You can use Content Providers for data sharing between your apps. You can learn more about Content Providers from the link below.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Note: If i'm not wrong to pass data with content providers between your apps, you need to sign your apps with same keystore.

You can also use Intents to pass data to your application. You can check it from below.

http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html

It's not a good practice but you can use shared preferences.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Comment: Alternative to ContentProviders are simple Intents, or (bound) services.

Answer (score 1):

A third, and possibly better way would be to use a `protocol` or custom `URI scheme`. By default this is the way that Android applications send and receive data. Example, when you click a url link sent to you via email, the app opens the default browser application. This is because the browser registered with the OS that it can handle URI's that match the pattern of a web uri.

See the attached link

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: I agree. This solution is the simplest in implementation

Answer (score 0):

Both  applications are yours so can easily make it.

1)By using shared preferences you can save data in mobile from app1 and get that data and use in app2 and vice versa.

SharedPreferences are useful for small data only .

2)Content provider do what  you are asking. A content provider is only required if you need to share data between multiple applications

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

In your situation you app must be a content provider

refer this what you are asking
http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/12/content-provider-in-android.html#.Vwsy1vl97IU

Comment: Thanks alot I used shared preferences

Answer (score 0):

Use Intent to pass data between apps along with BroadCastReceiver

**In your appOne Create**

1)Dynamic broadcast receiver inside your appOne activity on Particular Event call sendBroadcast(Intent)

Don't call activity as you mentioned above.Register a Broadcast receiver in appTwo with some action and sendBroadacst intent from appOne with same action mentioned in appTwo.
So when you fire sendbradcast(Intent) from appOne,appTwo listening for that intent will trigger and there you Call Activity of appTwo(Your MainActivity)
Inside onReceive method of appTwo check your activity is Active or not(If activity is active then sendBroadcast(Intent) from appTwo to refresh message in appTwo if not Call Activty)

**Now in your appTwo Create**

1)Static BroadCastReceiver to receive the intent with some action inside manifest when the app is not open

2)Dynamic broadcast receiver inside your appTwo activity if the app is open to refresh Message

Answer (score 0):

Following things need to be taken care during the implementation.

1. There are two Apps. App1 and App2. We need to send data from APP1 to APP2 and when APP2 finishes, we need to send Data back from APP2 to APP1.

### Steps :
-- Add android:exported = "true" in both the Apps manifest for the activities which you want the communication in between.

In App 1

```
private void launchApp2() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    //Need to register your intent filter in App2 in manifest file with same action.
    intent.setAction("com.example.app2.main"); // <packagename.main>
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("name", "ABC");
    intent.putExtra("data", bundle);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 101);
    } else {
    Log.d("App not installed")
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == 101) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle bundle = data.getBundleExtra("data");
            String username = bundle.getString("name");
            result.success(username);
        }
    } else {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
}
```

In App2 Manifest,

```
<activity android:name=".main">
    <intent-filter>    
        <!--The action has to be same as App1-->        
        <action android:name="com.example.app2.main" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

To get the Data in App2,

```
public getData (){
 Intent intent = new Intent();
 Bundle bundle = intent.getBundleExtra("data");
 String name = bundle.getString("name");
}
```

To send the data back to App1

```
public sendData(){
Intent intent = new Intent();
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 bundle.putString("name", "ABC");
 intent.putExtra("data", bundle)
 setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent)
 finish()
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use `Shared Preferences` with mode `MODE_WORLD_READABLE`

```
SharedPreferences sPref = activity.getPreferences(Activity.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
```

Save values in Preference:

Comment: Thanks alot : I use this link  http://androiddhamu.blogspot.in/2012/03/share-data-across-application-in.html , my problem solved

Comment: Why people down vote if the answer is correct or accepted ?