# How Pass String Value from One application to another application in android

Tags: android

This is my app A and have a string value "Hello" . I want to send this string value to app B.

```
String mystring = "Hello";
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.example.test");
if (launchIntent != null) {
    launchIntent.putExtra("success", mystring);
    startActivity(launchIntent);
}
```

This is my app B

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if (b != null) {
    String myString = b.getString("success");
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + myString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

On the receiving "app B" `myString` is received as `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send data from one application to other application in android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355860/how-to-send-data-from-one-application-to-other-application-in-android)

Comment: Directly you can't data from app one to another.

If you want to send some data from one app to another then you can use content provider.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Comment: Also relevant. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745243/data-sharing-between-two-applications

Answer (score 4):

On the manifest of app B,

You need to declare a intent filter with Category `DEFAULT` and `Action`=`com.your_app_package_name.your_app_name.ActivtiyAlpha`

Then you need to set that `action` in your `Intent` to start that activity for app A and send extra data in intent.

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.your_app_package_name.your_app_name.ActivtiyAlpha");
i.putExtra("KEY_DATA_EXTRA_FROM_ACTV_B", myString);
// add extras to any other data you want to send to b
launchIntent.putExtra("success",mystring);
startActivity(launchIntent);
```

Checkout [detailed Answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14355860/how-to-send-data-from-one-application-to-other-application-in-android?answertab=active#tab-top)