# Sending a token from one app to another avoiding the intent chooser

Tags: android

I have the following requirement:
I have 2 apps with the same sign key.

1. Login app A and get token(this toke is just a string)
2. From app A open and pass the token to B `<- HOW TO DO THIS`
3. Receive the token and login in B `and none other app`.

I'm reading this: https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/index.html  and I can't find how send data from one app to an specific app.

I don't want the chooser(https://stackoverflow.com/a/41185310/2139691) let the user send the token to any other app.

Comment: Why downvote? please comment and i can improve the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try find passing data through intent?

```
Intent launchIntent = 
getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.package.address");

launchIntent.putExtra("data", data);

startActivity(launchIntent);
```